# cant find module 'react-bootstrap'

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I installed necessray packages

> npm i react-bootstrap-validation", "npm install react-bootstrap

and updated typings

> npm update typings

but still getting this error;

[image]

How can I tell tyscript I already have that module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By running `npm update typings` you updated a tool, which is used to install typescript definitions. But you didn't install actual type definitions for react.

Actually you don't even need typings, because MS provided their own types publisher. Use this [page](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to search for any type definitions. What you need to do is to run `npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap`. This effectively installs typescript definitions for react-bootrstrap.

I really recommend you to take some basic course online around react+typescript (udemy or pluralsight), because these concepts might be very very complicated when start learning from ground without much experience in the field.

Comment: Hello Sergei, thanks for answer I installed it as you said, but this time it couldnt find the Object in module. please check the post

Comment: It looks like `react-bootstrap` doesn't have ButtonInput definition. Are you sure it's exists?

Comment: Did you mean `ButtonGroup` instead?

Comment: I was trying to use the sample here; https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-validation but buttongroup contains same controls.

Comment: Also I really wonder, what if you would do if you have encounter a package that has no types like 'react-validation'.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2125) - they removed `ButtonInput` in July 2016, last commit in [`react-bootstrap-validation`](https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation) is April 2016. That's the answer - `react-bootstrap-validation` repository didn't updated to match latest version of `react-bootstrap`.

Comment: In case if no definitions, you just use `var myvar: any = require("mypackage")`. In that case on type checking

Comment: _Take a look here - they removed ButtonInput in July 2016....._ - and I know, that's absolutely madness.... but that's the real state of opensource development for javascript nowadays... unfortunately.

Comment: this is why stackoverflow is life saver.. of course its nothing but a pretty website if experienced, helpful developers like you are not here. Thank you again

Comment: Thanks! The same way it's very pleasant to know that your help is valuable and recognized.